# Unable to create latest headless chrome for AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, aws-lambda-puppeteer

I have required to use the latest headless chrome with puppeteer on AWS Lambda and for that, I have referred: https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/blob/master/docs/chrome.md.

I already tried all the following approch to create headless chrome using given instruction but won't work and will get the same error as below.

1. Locally (build headless Chromium locally is with Docker)
2. With AWS EC2 (build Chromium using an EC2 Spot Instance (spot-block))
3. AmazonLinux on EC2 (build Chromium without Docker using just the build.sh script)

**ERROR:**

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/Headless'
[1/26797] STAMP obj/build/win/default_exe_manifest.stamp
[2/26797] ACTION //build/util:webkit_version(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
[3/26797] STAMP obj/base/numerics/base_numerics.stamp
[4/26797] ACTION //base:build_date(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
[5/26797] STAMP obj/build/buildflag_header_h.stamp
[6/26797] STAMP obj/base/util/type_safety/type_safety.stamp
[7/26797] CXX obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o
FAILED: obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o 
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o.d -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"373424-64a362e7-1\" -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCXXABI_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_NODISCARD -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=361348 -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=bcc994cc6e5d4d6f0eec8b44e7f0a65f5a1a7b90 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -I../.. -Igen -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fPIC -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -pthread -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -fcrash-diagnostics-dir=../../tools/clang/crashreports -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -fcomplete-member-pointers -m64 -march=x86-64 -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -no-canonical-prefixes -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra-semi -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-sizeof-array-div -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -std=c++14 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++ -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++abi/trunk/include --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -c ../../base/base_switches.cc -o obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o

../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /build/chromium/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
The command '/bin/sh -c sh /build.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: did you install build essentials

Comment: i haven't use this plugin, but looks like some c++ related error

Comment: are you getting this during the installation or when you invoke the lambda?

Comment: @ArunK I think you did not read a question properly. I try to create the latest headless chrome for my lambda function which runs on Nodejs 12.x with puppeteer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of implementation/orchestration was changed in a lambda to use headless chrome with puppeteer compared to earlier.

I have used [chrome-aws-lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) to run headless chrome with puppeteer in lambda for Nodejs10.x/12.x. Amazon has already announced EOL (End Of Life) for Nodejs8.x in lambda.

Amazon is using Amazon Linux AMI 2 for Node.js10.x/12.x and Amazon Linux AMI for Node.js8.x. Amazon Linux AMI 2 does not have some of the dependencies which will create problems to run headless chrome with puppeteer in Nodejs10.x/12.x inside lambda and therefore will use the lambda layer to run headless chrome with puppeteer on Node.js10.x/12.x.

[chrome-aws-lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) will provide us the latest version of puppeteer and headless chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I have had this problems as well, if is not required for your app to be hosted on AWS. The easiest way, to put your app in the cloud is by using Google Cloud Functions with a decent amount of RAM. Here is a video showing you how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8THvr03FaY

Comment: Already production running with nodejs8.x and will require to update to nodejs12.x as nodejs8.x is EOL soon on aws lambda

Comment: Completely off topic. Question is related to AWS Lambda, not Google.